# How to make a position:relative div centered vertically?

Tags: css, position, center

How to make a position:relative div centered in its parent element vertically?
For example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div style="position:relative;" class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make $('.child') centered vertically in $('.parent')?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery selectors?

Comment: oh, I just use it to describe the element...it doesn't mean anything

Comment: Have a read of this: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this css instead of using table directly

```
.parent
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table;
}
.child
{
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below `CSS`

```
.parent
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.child
{
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use  `table`  to make it vertically centered.

```
<div class="parent">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                <div>Centered div</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have other child <div> to position? Does `table` way make sense in a complex layout webpage?